# Can someone explain me this jmeter test result?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

So I recorded a script for the login scenario:

**1. url hit** is hitting the url

**2. login** is passing credentials and clicking the login button

[This is my jmeter screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIm4q.png)
Now my **url hit** is having 55% error rate while the **login** has 21% only.

Sometimes **url hit** has 100% error rate whereas **login** has 0% error rate.

So i want to know what does this mean.? If a user is not able to hit my url then how will they be able to login.? This is something I want to understand.

[Error on **url hit** is shown 504 gateway time-out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aU2kd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you know that users are able to log in? JMeter automatically treats [HTTP status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful so even if your login fails and the server returns a "positive" HTTP status code JMeter will automatically treat the request as successful.

So I would recommend using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to ensure that your test is doing what it is supposed to be doing and you're really hitting the URL and not getting stuck at the login page.

Going forward you could use i.e. [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved) to ensure that the response contains what it should be containing (for example presence of "welcome" text or presence of "Logout" link) or doesn't contain elements which should not be present (given you're logged in you should not be seeing login form)

Comment: hey @Dmitri , Thanks for the help. I came to know this when I actually saw the html response data. Thank you very much. I appreciate your help.